# Expand parts of url into rows

Tags: postgresql

its possible when parsing string "projects/project/23" expand it into this result:

```
projects
projects/project
projects/project/23
```

I think I can use lag/lead window functions and make this SQL query:

```
select  lag(unnest, 1, '') OVER () || '/' || unnest AS unnest
from unnest(string_to_array('projects/project/23', '/'))
```

but it doesnt work. How to make it?

Thank you.

**One solution:**

Ok I found one solution (but I think its not optimal)

```
WITH t AS (
        SELECT  row_number() OVER (),
                string_to_array('projects/project/23', '/')
        FROM unnest(string_to_array('projects/project/23', '/'))
)
SELECT  array_to_string(string_to_array[1:t.row_number], '/')
FROM t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main part of the answer - you need to use [string_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) rolling total:

```
with cte as (
    select a, row_number() over() as rn
    from unnest(string_to_array('projects/project/23', '/')) as a
)
select string_agg(a, '/') over(order by rn)
from cte
```

<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1609)</kbd>

It will work, but order of elements is not guaranteed (although I cannot make the query work wrong). To **100% guarantee** order of elements, you can use [generate_subscripts](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) function:

```
with cte as (
    select string_to_array('projects/project/23', '/') as a
), cte2 as (
    select a, generate_subscripts(a, 1) as i from cte
)
select string_agg(a[i], '/') over(order by i)
from cte2
```

<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1614)</kbd>